# get progress in onStopTrackingTouch not onProgressChanged in seekbar

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I'm new to android development , 
I use `onProgressChanged` to get current progress as progress is a parameter of the function .

but **I want to get only the final value of progress** when user release the `seekbar` not the Immediate value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you saying you don't want to have to implement `onProgressChanged` (and `onStartTrackingTouch`) and only implement `onStopTrackingTouch`?  If so, no way to avoid implementing all three (without customizing `OnSeekBarChangeListenter`), but first two can just be empty.

Comment: ok , i mean that "when use slide the seekbar" I want to get the last value only "when user release the seekbar" but in "onProgressChanged" I get the progress value for every move of the seekbar . "I want the final value only" , which handler's method should I use ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `onStopTrackTouch` method defined in `OnSeekBarChangeListener` is called when the user stops sliding the `SeekBar` (i.e., has finished the touch gesture) and provides the "final value".