# Can I get the "int progress" from onProgressChanged inside onStopTrackingTouch

Tags: android-studio, progress, seekbar

I want to make an "if" acoording progress's value but int progress is apparently only inside

```
onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
```

I'd like to use this progress inside

```
onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
```

I saw this quetsion: [get progress in onStopTrackingTouch not onProgressChanged in seekbar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13440965/9329115)

But it didn't answer my question and I'm not allowed to make a comment there...

Comment: I found something on internet might be the answer but have to get home to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to do that:

```
getProgress()
```